# How to launch a process window at a specified location, using c#

Tags: c#, exec

I need to launch 5 different processes and display the windows at specific X, Y coordinates.  I have tried the following:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool repaint);

for (int k = 0; k < numberOfProcess;k++ )
{
    myProcess = new Process();
    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = uitbFileLocation.Text;
    myProcess.Start();
    if ((i + 1) * Delta < 2 * R)
    {
        X = i * Delta;
    }
    else
    {
        X = 2 * R;
        sign = -1;
        i = 0;
    }
    bool one = MoveWindow(myProcess.MainWindowHandle, X, Calcuate(R, X, sign), 334, 362, false);
```

but "moveWindow" always returns false and nothing happens.

Comment: What is the value of `myProcess.MainWindowHandle`? is it 0? Can you invoke `var error_code = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` after you invoke `MoveWindow` and see what is the value of `error_code`?

Comment: Why are you setting `CreateNoWindow` to true?

Comment: i dont no why i copy that section from another post in this site.i just want to say my process has to start at X Y location

Comment: myProcess.MainWindowHandle=1771150

Comment: What about the result of calling `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()`?

Comment: i dont get it.could you explain more?

Comment: After you call `MoveWindow` and it returns `false`, call `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()` and tell us what that method returns. This will help us know what the problem is.

Comment: invalid window handler 1400. i wrote this line of code after that boolean.
messagebox.show(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().toString())